# Mass downvote after deleting a question

Tags: support, serial-voting

I became target of mass downvote after I deleted one of the questions I asked (revenge downvoting for not upvoting the answer?) and now I can't ask any question again. What can I do now?
[image]

Comment: I dont know if its revenge downvote tbh, just possible one, however its a mass one (maybe bot did it) and  there is no explanation for the downvotes

Comment: When did this happen? Likely it'll be automatically caught and reversed and everything will be fine

Comment: like 40 mins ago, but I wonder why such mass dwonvotes lead to account suspension of the victim not of the serial downvoter

Comment: Whether it was actually revenge or not, the solution is the same: If someone did go and downvote a significant number of your posts in rapid succession, a nightly process will reverse those votes and everything will be as if the votes had never happened.

Comment: "Please do not try to get help on this issue on meta or by flagging for a moderator. All they will do is tell you to wait for the voting fraud script to run (they can't run it for you just this once).  If the 24 hours has already passed and the suspicious votes have not been reversed, you can then flag one of your own posts and explain what happened so a moderator can look into it."

Comment: The question ban is unfortunate but it'll fix itself once the serial voting script runs. If it doesn't, flag one of the posts and explain.